# CPQ: Automating the Selection of Product Options based on fields in custom objects. Product Rule or Apex?

Tags: apex, cpq, product

My use case is I have a screen flow that asks questions that are needed to populate the quote correctly ie: Are there curbs involved, and if so, what concrete PSI is needed: 3500, 4000, 4500; Are there sidewalks involved, and if so, what is their thickness: 4" or 6". These answers are stored in custom objects with lookup fields to the quote. Upon completion of the flow, Quote Line Groups (QLG) are added to the Quote through the Flow with a custom field designating 'Curb' or 'Sidewalk'. There is a trigger for when QLGs are created that inserts a product bundle into the QLG based on the custom field in the QLG.

What I need help with is automatic product option selection. For Curbs and Sidewalks the Concrete PSI is grouped in a feature of there respective bundles as three product options. Size is also a feature with two product options. How do I make a product selection rule that selects the correct option in each feature based on a field in a custom object? Would a better solution be to use apex to query that object and select the product options? If so what objects and fields cause the selection of product options of a product bundle on a quote line?

I appreciate any help or guidance.